# How to create an APK

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

I just updated xamarin in visual studio.  It is 4.2.... who knows exactly.  Before I did this update, I would just click build>generate apk and create my apk.  Now that isn't there anymore.  So how do I do that?

Thanks Xamarin for reminding me to never, ever, ever update if everything is working already.

Comment: Right click and choose Archive according to [the documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/#archive)

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-archiving-and-publishing-made-easy/

Answer (score 0):

1. click on the drop down menu on the toolbar at the top (usually with
   android icon and name of your application)
2. select Edit configurations.
3. click plus sign at top left corner or press alt+insert.
4. select Gradle.
5. choose your module as Gradle project.
6. in Tasks: enter assemble.
7. press OK.
8. press play.